# Linq to SQL: Group By and Sum()

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I'm very new to linq so this should be pretty easy to answer, but I've had a hard time finding the answer.

I have the following LINQ statement, which performs a simple linq query and assigns the resulting values labels on an asp.net web form:

```
        Dim db As New MeetingManagerDataContext
    Dim q = From s In db.vwRoomAvailabilities _
                Where s.MeetingID = lblMeetingID.Text _
                Select s.AllRequestedSingles, s.AllRequestedDoubles, s.AllBookedSingles, s.AllBookedDoubles, SinglesNeeded = s.AllRequestedSingles - s.AllBookedDoubles, DoublesNeeded = s.AllRequestedDoubles - s.AllBookedDoubles

    lblSinglesRequested.Text = "Singles Requested: " & q.FirstOrDefault.AllRequestedSingles
    lblSinglesBooked.Text = "Singles Booked: " & q.FirstOrDefault().AllBookedSingles
    lblSinglesNeeded.Text = "Singles Needed: " & q.FirstOrDefault().SinglesNeeded
    lblDoublesRequested.Text = "Doubles Requested: " & q.FirstOrDefault().AllRequestedDoubles
    lblDoublesBooked.Text = "Doubles Booked: " & q.FirstOrDefault().AllBookedDoubles
    lblDoublesNeeded.Text = "Doubles Needed: " & q.FirstOrDefault().DoublesNeeded
```

Originally, there was going to be only a single row result and you can see I'm using FirstOrDefault() to grab that single value which works great.  But the design has changed, and multiple rows can now be returned by the query. I need to now Group By the MeetingID above, and SUM each of the selected columns (i.e. s.AllRequestedDoubles).

I've found lots of grouping and summing samples but none seem to fit this scenario very well.

Can you help me modify the above LINQ to Sum the resulting values instead of just showing the first row result values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
From s In db.vwRoomAvailabilities
Where s.MeetingID = lblMeetingID.Text
Group by s.MeetingID 
into SumAllRequestedDoubles = sum(s.AllRequestedDoubles),
     SumAggregate2 = sum(s.SomeField2),
     SumAggregate3 = sum(s.SomeField3)
Select SumAllRequestedDoubles, SumAggregate2, SumAggregate3
```

That will get you started for performing a SUM on that single column.

You'll need to project each SUM'd column into a new aliased column (like i did above).

Also, as you're new to LINQ-SQL, check out [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) - it will rock your world.

Comment: So I would need to write an individual statment like that for each column I need to sum?  No way to sum all of the columns in one Select?

Comment: Well if i understand your question, you dont want to sum all of the columns into one single resulting field, you need to sum the records for each column (sum singles req'd, sum singles booked, etc). Therefore you'll need to supply each column. Think about if it you wrote it in raw T-SQL, you'll still need to write SELECT SUM(a), SUM(b), SUM(c), etc.

Comment: Right,  the sum(a), sum(b), sum(c) is all in a single statment, it sounds like you are saying I need to write a completely seperate FROM/WHERE/GROUP/SELECT linq statement for each column I need to sum.

Can you show 2 of my columns summed in your example code?

Comment: Pleasure! p.s i like the avatar. "Its not easy being really really, ridiculously good looking", hahaha.